i am getting error in android studio on kotlin while i am working with swapping(next or prev) images with imageButton
click here xml layout
code :
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var currentimage = 0
    lateinit var image : ImageView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val next = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.next)
        val prev = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.prev)
        val images = arrayOf(findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.pic0),
            findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.pic1),
            findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.pic2),
            findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.pic3),
            findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.pic4)
        )
        images[currentimage].alpha = 1F

        next.setOnClickListener {
            images[currentimage].alpha = 0F

            currentimage = (images.size+currentimage+1)%images.size

            images[currentimage].alpha = 1F



        }
        prev.setOnClickListener {
            next.setOnClickListener {
                images[currentimage].alpha = 0F

                currentimage = (images.size+currentimage-1)%images.size

                images[currentimage].alpha = 1F

        }

can i get this reslove i am trying to solve this

Pease [edit] your question and describe the problem that you have. Also, please properly format the code.

Please share the stacktrace when the exception is thrown.

Maybe I don't understand correctly your question. but I think you can't  switch images to next and to previously.
Try to add your images NOT ImageView to list. Like this:
val listOfImages = listOf(R.drawable.first, R.drawable.second, R.drawable.third)

After this rewrite your click listener:
next.setOnClickListener {
     currentimage++
     mainImage.setImageResourse(list[currentimage])
}

prew.setOnClickListener {
     currentimage--
     mainImage.setImageResourse(list[currentimage])
}


MainImage

It's your only one ImageView.
And you need to add the “if else” statement to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

it showming same java.lang.NullPointerException

Check all places, image , name of images and imageView. Show all logcat , not just a name of exception.
